# UITextField, Text blurred when focus on in zoom mode

Tags: ios, uitextfield

### Heading

I lost in this problem for long time and did not find answer on Google or stackoverflow.

I added setContentScaleFactor and now when focus in field, text will be blurred. While focus out, text will be sharp.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourTextField setContentScaleFactor:scale];
```

Call this Every time you are zooming.

This may helps you.

Comment: Yes, I do this. But the problem is when I typing(cursor blink), text will be fuzzy. If I close keyboard, text will be clear.